# Use opacity on only one element in a block in CSS

Tags: html, css

Can you I use `opacity` only on one property of element?

```
nav ul li::after {
    background: grey;
    content: "";
    height: 3px;
    width: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    box-shadow: 15px 0px 5px 2.5px #0ff;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Can I use opacity only on the box-shadow?

Comment: You can use something like `rgba(0,0,0,0.1)` as the box-shadow color to control the opacity.

Comment: Instead of using `opacity` on `box-shadow` property, use opacity in color you have used for `box-shadow`. Also properties are applied to element not other properties of element.

Answer (score 0):

No. Opacity applies to the *element* it applies to (and affects all its children). It can't be applied to specific properties (and border-shadow is a property, not an element).

You *can* however specify a [translucent colour](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#rgb-functions) for the shadow.

```
box-shadow: 15px 0px 5px 2.5px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

`box-shadow: 15px 0px 5px 2.5px rgba(15, 240, 255, 0.5);`

`0.5` being the opacity.